# I cant get the image in my /var/www/efs/image/ folder using html <img src>

Tags: html, reactjs, linux, file

I am working on my project that will get the image based on users ID. My image stored in /var/www/efs/image folder. I tried to put the directory like this `<img src={"/var/www/efs/images/"} runat="server" ></img>` but it just cant see it. when i check the error, it says 404 and it just append my directory to my website `(https://mywebsite.com/var/www/efs/images/subscriber_image.png)`.

why is that I cant get my image? What should I do? Thanks in advance for the answer :) hope someone can help me with this. im stuck :(

btw im using amazon linux

Comment: Q: So why don't you just use the relative path from your web root (e.g. `images/`, or `efs/images/`)?

Comment: hi @paulsm4 I tried that but same error. It just append to my website just like I said above. still cant get the image.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the src attribute is looking for a hosted resource or a local internal resource. You can't use a resource located in the system that isn't exposed via the website files/project. This is because of system security issues. So in short, if you want to access that file, move it so an assets folder within your website's project.

Comment: hi @Kwright02 I already did it in my (public/image/subscriber_image.png) but still not working 

`<img src="public/image/1000132566-test3.png" runat="server" ></img>`

Comment: put a / before public

Comment: still not working bro :( it says 404 in my devtool and when i hover on it, it says (`https://mywebsite.com/public/image/1000132566-test3.png`)

Comment: well if you're not hosting it at /public/image/whatever.png then ofc it won't find it. It seems like you're not hosting it properly but I'm not sure since I can't see your code

Answer (score 0):

try The absolute path
`<img src="//www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg" title="Title of image" alt="alt text here"/>`